# Verifying time format validity in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time

I have been looking around [MySQL's date and time functions page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for quite a while now, but I fail to find a function which can indicate if a time format is valid to be used in, for example, the `STR_TO_DATE` function. The user supplies a format, and I wish to accept as wide a range of formats as possible. The format may be used later in the script in conjunction with MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE` function, which in turn returns NULL upon failure (which is what I would like to avoid, through pre-warning the user when he provides an invalid time format). I intend to test the formats somehow with the help of a temporary table.

I can't test the formats validity by using the `STR_TO_DATE` function, because the string values that will be passed to it will eventually be generated by the user (on an undefined point of time in the future), so I have no idea which strings are going to be passed to it. I had hoped the `DATE_FORMAT` function could resolve my issue, but it simply ignores any invalid format specifiers (for example, `%Q` means nothing, and will translate to `Q`). Under no condition NULL will be returned nor will a warning be produced.

Any ideas?

Edit: the only roughly reliable solution I could come up with was making a list of all MySQL's supported format specifiers and compare those with all format specifiers present in the format provided by the user.

`preg_match_all("/(?:(?<!%)|(?<=%%))(?:%%)*%([^%])/", $format, $matches);`

The regular expression lists all characters that are preceded by an odd amount of percent sign occurrences. (Which is necessary, as percent signs escape themselves.) Now `$matches[1]` contains the list of these characters.

Comment: before inserting into db just use some date formatting. If you insert wrong format, you will get error

Comment: @s.d The user provides the date format before any dates are to be inserted into the database. These moment may differ by seconds, but could also be weeks. Consequently, I do intend to warn the user immediatly upon providing the date format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the string only contains valid specifiers, then create a list of the 32 format specifiers...

```
a, b, c, d, D, e, f, h, H, i, I, j, k, l, m, M, p, r, s, S, T, u, U, v, V, w, W, x, X, y, Y, %
```

Then iterate through the format string and check for valid specifiers...

```
// pseudo-code... pretend format is an array of the format's characters
function is_valid_format(format) {
  for (x = 0; x < format.length; ++x) 
    if (format[x] == "%" &&
        (x + 1 >= format.length || 
        specifiers does not contain format[x + 1])
      return false

  return true
}
```

You may also consider offering a list of preset date format strings the user can select from. Unless the user has memorized their format string or memorized the specifiers, I would much more prefer to select a date format string.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery validation engine to validate date format from client side.

From PHP you can validate date ( MySQL date format '2013-09-14' ) as

```
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date)) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be achieved using MySQL triggers.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.date_column REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$') = 0 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Wrong Input';
END IF;
END //

DELIMITER;
```

This is an example set that will check for user input with format **"YYYY-MM-DD"** and will **throw message "Wrong Input"** if the user input is different then the format specified.

Regular expression can be adjusted as per the needs.